# Do functions called from parent functions on dispatch_queue get placed on main or dispatch_queue?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I am working in Swift 3.0 currently. I am wondering if functions called from functions that are placed on a Dispatch_Queue are also placed on the same Dispatch_Queue as well, or are they placed back on Main?

I included an example snippet below, in this case I'm wondering if calledFromParentFunction() is called from MyQueue since parentFunction1() that calls it is placed on MyQueue, or does calledFromParentFunction() get called on Main since it wasn't explicitly called on MyQueue?

```
let MyQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "My Queue", attributes: [], target: nil)

parentFunction1() {
    calledFromParentFunction()
}

calledFromParentFunction() {
    print("Is this on Main or MyQueue?")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    MyQueue.async { [unowned self] in
        parentFunction1()
    }
}
```

Comment: `Thread` has a method described as `class var isMainThread: Bool` that might help you find out for any specific code path.

Comment: The entire call stack will be on the same queue unless there is specific code to do otherwise.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's on the custom queue. You can prove it with this hack:

```
func calledFromParentFunction() {
    let name = __dispatch_queue_get_label(nil)
    let queue =  String(cString: name, encoding: .utf8)!
    print("This is on", queue)
}
```

Comment: Great, I figured as much but wanted to double check. Thank you!